# Create all possible vector combinations for euclidean coordinate system

Tags: python, vector, permutation, coordinate-systems

I know there are several questions on stackoverflow about permutations of lists and lists of lists, however, I did not find a smart solution for my following problem:

I want to create all possible vector bases for an euclidean coordinate system:

```
import numpy as np
euclidean_system = np.array([[1,0,0],
                             [0,1,0],
                             [0,0,1]])
```

Now I would like something like the permutations/product function from itertools to type:

```
permutations = *desired_function*(euclidean_system)
```

and then get

```
permutations = [[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],
                [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]],
                [[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]] # and so on
               ]
```

Up to now this is easily possible with itertools.permutations, but I would like to also include the cases where 1, 2 or 3 vectors are negative, e.g.

```
additional_permutations = [[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],
                          [[-1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],
                          [[1,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,-1]] # and so on
                          ]
```

I know I could type this by hand but I wonder if there is a clever solution to this.
Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at `np.meshgrid`. It does output what you want but in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `itertools.product`.  It creates a generator for the Cartesian coordinates of the input iterables.

```
from itertools import product
list(product([-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]))
# returns:
[(-1, -1, -1),
 (-1, -1, 0),
 (-1, -1, 1),
 (-1, 0, -1),
 (-1, 0, 0),
 (-1, 0, 1),
 (-1, 1, -1),
 (-1, 1, 0),
 (-1, 1, 1),
 (0, -1, -1),
 (0, -1, 0),
 (0, -1, 1),
 (0, 0, -1),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, -1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, -1, -1),
 (1, -1, 0),
 (1, -1, 1),
 (1, 0, -1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, -1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: i know the product function from itertools already, however, this is not exactly the output i need. I need my output to be in the form of a LIST containing 3x3 MATRICES with all different combinations (ordering) of unit x/y/z vectors (positive and negative 1s).